# Machine learning and time series

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, assumptions

I am an undergraduate student currently taking a times series analysis course this term. The course only covers statistical models, then I have two questions:

1. Do people use machine learning methods to forecast stock price movement?
2. Do we have to make statistical assumption to forecast time series?

I know these questions are probably dumb and arrogant since I am new to this field. I googled very briefly, then I made a summary:

- Time series machine learning does not make any statistical assumption at all
- People use machine learning to forecast stock price movement, but not
  as much as using statistical models
- Statistical models are not better than machine learning methods in
  terms of accuracy

Is my summary correct?